# Can I take points for bounty reputation for myself?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I've started bounty a few days ago with a question (300 points) , and none has answered or commented.

And today, it looks I am very close to the solution.

If I answer the question and adopt it as an answer, do I get the 300 points back ?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is negative, according to the [help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.